# Catching errors with setMainFrameURL in a Webview

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, webview

I am using the following code to populate a webView in my Mac app...

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://joeworkman.net"];
[self setMainFrameURL:[url absoluteString]];
```

I would like to be able to capture when there are errors loading this URL and then instead load a local HTML file stored within my app. This way the users gets presented with a presentable error instead of an ugly 500 server error (if that was the case). Not to mention that most users would not know what that meant anyhow.

Comment: You would probably want to catch it in a delegate instead of `setMainFrameURL`.

Comment: Yes. I do need to implement a delegate but I just could not figure out which one that would be. I am not sure its possible with the code that I put above. I think I need to call NSURLRequest myself.

Comment: Possibly.  Call it on a separate thread, and if there's an error then just change the URL of the webview to your local local HTML file.